# Why is the misspelling "writting" so common?

Tags: spelling, orthography

I find it peculiar that so many English learners seem to think that "writing" is written with two T:s. Is this an influence from some other language (which one?) or somehow otherwise rational? I would think it should be obvious that *"*writting"* would have to rhyme with *"hitting*", while *"writing"* rhymes with *"biting".*

Examples:
https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=writting and even https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22writting%22

Possibly related:
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8994/differentiating-between-written-and-writing/8996#8996

Generally, you can understand why someone makes a particular misspelling. You can explain why someone writes *"separate"* with a second E (because the second syllable is unstressed and thus not often properly articulated) or why *"their"* gets mixed up with *"there";* or even why someone might type *"seplling"* instead of *"spelling".* There are rational reasons for those mistakes. But this one has me stumped.

Comment: It's not just learners; there are plenty of native English speakers that cannot spell.'Writting' is quite a common error.

Comment: But why? If "bicking" for "biking" was also common I would see the pattern; but it's not.

Comment: There are many typical spelling mistakes and here we cannot really answer that question. Why does anyone make a spelling mistake? Because they are not good spellers or they haven't reread what they wrote.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not a question about English per se. It could apply to any language.

Comment: @Lambie This is _specifically_ about a _particular_ English word. This is definitely not asking "why are some people poor spellers".

Comment: A person who mispells writing as writting is very likely to be making other spelling errors as well. This is especially true in English compared to, say, Spanish where you write what you hear.

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant. There are inexplicable typos all the time but they are typically so infrequent as to drown in other noise. It's the _systematic_ misspelling of this particular word which makes it interesting and intriguing.

Comment: @Lambie - les barbarismes comme « dilemne » à la place de « dilemme »

Comment: Sometimes we think we are seeing something over and over and it then stands out in our minds. However, that can just be an impression.

Comment: @Lambie I challenge you to find words which are misspelled with this frequency. There are currently 68 hits for _"writting"_ on this site, 41 for _"seperate",_ and only four for _"definate"._ Those are pet peeves of mine, sure (and I have probably corrected a few in the past) but that, to me, is significant.

Comment: @tripleee: You'd never make a statistician! I get 93 instances of **writting** on ELL, compared to 17400 instances of **writing**, so that's an error rate of less than 0.5%. By comparison, 720 instances of **seperate** instead of **separate** (with 7850 hits for the correct spelling) is an error rate of almost 10%

Comment: Those are _also_ interesting numbers, but the absolute frequency is more relevant for establishing whether it's something you would notice as a recurring phenomenon. If I misspell "_zoonomic"_ once after noticing that it previously did not occur in the search results on this site at all, it would appear that the misspelling _"zoonomik"_ has a 50% error rate.

Comment: I can only repeat what I said before - you'd never make a statistician! Your original question asked for an explanation of why people (specifically, nns?) misspell ***writing*** (answer - they don't do so *very* often, but there are reasons that "explain" even the relatively low error rate). But now you seem to be asking ***why you notice it so much*** (answer - because the total ***sample size*** for that word is very high, ***and*** it's a more "egregious" error than ***seperate,*** which has a much lower sample size anyway).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I think someone upvoted your comment just because of the first sentence. I suggest almost no native Anglophones capable of spelling their own name would write ***writting*** for ***writing***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _One of the comments English teachers dread to see on their evaluations is “The professor really helped me improve my writting.”_ Prof Paul Brians, Washington State University

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Well, yes - but surely the reason they dread seeing that is because it's prima facie evidence that they've got to cater for non-native Anglophones in their class (on reflection, more likely it's just a facetious joke! :)

Comment: What research have you done? What explanations have you considered? How did you investigate them? What evidence do you have that it's misspelt more than expected or more than similar words? You might want to read up on [frequency illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_illusion).

Comment: @StuartF It is common enough to have made it to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Lists_of_common_misspellings/W

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one of the comments in the [linked ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8994/differentiating-between-written-and-writing/8996#8996) might offer a clue. Someone observes "There's one T in write, and there's one T in writing. Easy as pie." Someone else exposes how this won't do as a universal rule: "There's one T in 'put', and there's one T in 'putting'. Oops. ;-)"

Perhaps some are trying to extrapolate a general rule or procedure from "hit -> hitting," "sit -> sitting," and are missing the fact that this is about "long vowels" vs. short vowels. The "t" has been doubled in these cases to avoid the phonetics rule that "vowel-consonant-vowel makes the first vowel long," so "hiting" might be pronounced "height-ing." Meanwhile, "light -> lighting," "loot -> looting": these vowels are already long so don't need the "t" doubled. But this phonetics distinction might be hard for learners.

Comment: It's a good point about the phonetics distinction being harder for learners. Many (feasibly even *most*) learners are exposed as much to English in ***writing*** (no pun intended! :) as they are to actual ***speech***. Whereas for almost all native Anglophones, the proportion of their exposure to English in writing is *tiny* compared the amount of spoken English they both generate and understand. So the pronunciation differences stand out much more clearly to us natives because we already know *(accurately)* what the words ***sound*** like without devoting many brain cells to the process.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And I don't have any kind of data, but I might surmise that phonetics-based mistakes might be even more common the more different the learner's original language is. When I learn Spanish and French, the vowels definitely behave differently, but I'm using the same alphabet and many phonemes are still the same, or are "mapped" to a different sound but still behave consistently. I couldn't imagine learning anything that uses a different alphabet!

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I suspect because of its unique history, English *orthography* is further removed from the (current) *spoken* version than any other language. But in a few years time hardly anyone will read or write much anyway, since we're within spitting distance of reliable conversion to audio through something as  unobtrusive as a pair of reading glasses.

Comment: French orthography is also quite far removed from the spoken language. At least one scholar of writing systems (Geoffrey Sampson) argues that this could even be argued to constitute a feature, in that whilst it makes writing (correctly) harder, it makes reading easier, because the idiosyncrasies of the spelling conventions help you recognize the correct meaning of the word more rapidly than if you had to grapple with many identical homographs or at least similarly spelled words. It's easy to tell _yore_ apart from _your_ and _you're,_ where a more phonetic system would spell them all as _jor._

Answer (score 2):

***Native*** Anglophones tend to recognize fairly early on that many vowel symbols *(letters)* can reflect two or more different sounds.

Specifically, they notice that when **i, a, e,...** are followed by a ***double*** consonant before the next vowel, the vowel ***before*** that doubled consonant is likely to be "short" compared to the same sequence with only a ***single*** consonant. Hence...

> ***writer, writing*** - single consonant, long (diphthong) 'i'
> ***written*** - double consonant, short 'i'
> ***rotor,motor*** - single consonant, long 'o'
> ***rotten, cotton*** - double consonant, short 'o'
> ***mating, rating***
> ***matter, rattle***
> ...

Non-native speakers probably don't pick up on this (fairly consistently observed) principle so early / easily as the natives. But obviously anyone *could* make this kind of mistake. It's similar but not identical to the pronunciation differences between ***backing*** and ***baking*** (where ***baccing*** isn't valid - but ***tobacco*** with a short 'a' is).

---

Note that my first set of examples all involve single or doubt /t/. But the same principle can apply to many other consonants: ***ruby | rubbed, rider | ridden, raging | ragged, taped | tapped, squared | jarred, miser | missive,...***

---

To guard against it being deleted as an ephemeral comment, I'll just include her my "explanation" for why non-native Anglophones in particular might be more likely to misspell ***writting*** (but bear in mind that's an exceptionally common word on this site, so even a relatively low error rate leads to quite a lot of examples).

Many (feasibly even most) learners are exposed as much to English in ***writing*** (no pun intended! :) as they are to actual speech. Whereas for almost all native Anglophones, the proportion of their exposure to English in writing is tiny compared the amount of spoken English they both generate and understand. So the pronunciation differences stand out much more clearly to natives because we already know *(accurately, without thinking)* what the words sound like. It takes more mental effort for learners (who maybe don't know the sounds accurately anyway), so they have less "spare" capacity to absorb implications and recognize patterns in spelling.

Comment: When you found those 93 mispellings on ELL of writing, did you happen to notice who the people were? Such as native versus non-native? I agree that non-natives would make more spelling errors (all other things remaining equal) than natives.

Comment: It's not always obvious who's a native Anglophone and who isn't, so answering your question could be a *lot* of work. But unless it was just a typo, I'd be surprised if *any* native Anglophone likely to post here would misspell ***writing*** - that's just too basic a mistake!

Comment: But then your explanation would predict that we ought to see more instances of _"backing"_ pro _"baking"_ etc; but I don't think we do.

Comment: @tripleee: That doesn't follow at all! Apart from anything else, there are only 128 instances of the word ***backing*** on ELL, so with a 0.5% error rate we might expect *maybe* one misspelling. There are none, in fact, primarily because as I said in my answer, that particular "doubled consonant" case is **similar but not identical**. And most people will be taught (or notice for themselves) the differences between 'c', 'k', 'ck' when they come between vowel sounds (and maybe they'll also notice that 'cc' and 'kk' are *extremely* rare sequences in English, making this obviously different).

Comment: Still, if this was a pattern, you would expect _"smitting"_ for _"smite",_ _"bitting"_ for _"bite",_ _"smilling"_ for _"smile",_ etc etc.

Comment: Feasibly. But it would be very difficult to research that point the same as with ***writing*** because that's probably the *only* word in this general class of "words having derivatives where a doubled-up consonant reflects shortening of the preceding vowel" that gets written anywhere near so often on this site. And as I keep saying, the error rate for ***writting*** is already incredibly low compared to, say, ***seperate***. But any learner who knows words like ***smite*** is probably *way* past the level of ignorantly misspelling ***smiting*** anyway.